# Slideshow will not work in Google Chrome at default zoom level?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a JQuery slideshow which rotates a set of images every few seconds and roundrobins back to the initial one when finished. I'm using CSS Translation which should work in Chrome as of 2010, but it doesn't seem to work for me. In Firefox and IE it works, but not Chrome. Interestingly, when I zoom out or zoom in, just change the zoom level in any which way, it then begins to work, just not on page load. Why is this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(slide, 1500);
    function slide() {
        $("#slider").css("transform", "translateX(" + $(this).index() * +(i * 1000) + "px)");
        if (i == 2) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#slider_container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#slider {
    width: 3000px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
#slider img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.bannered {
    max-width: 1000px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider_container">
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6C1jhl0.png" class="bannered" alt="" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nTmz9LF.png" class="bannered" alt="" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qFZIvPr.png" class="bannered" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `position: relative;` to your `#slider img`.

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. I inspected the console and saw that the translateX was being applied, and could see the ```#slider``` container moving properly. But the images weren't flowing with it. So I thought that maybe setting position to relative would "force" the browser to properly consider their positions against their parent, and it worked. This might actually be a browser bug (especially considering that zooming in/out makes the translate work). Perhaps it's worth submitting to [Chromium Issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).